# New monitor prevents computer from waking via DisplayPort

Tags: boot, graphics-card, display, gpu, displayport

I just installed a new Samsung monitor and am not able to boot when it is running via DisplayPort (DP).

The PC boots fine when running via HDMI or DVI, but if I am running via DP it won't even post to BIOS (fans and case LEDs still run though). If I unplug the DP cable in this state, the computer continues to boot (I can tell because the LEDs of my keyboard and mouse turn on, and I can blindly type in my password after waiting and it will be logged in after plugging the monitor back in). If I plug it the DP cable back in, everything is fine. Then whenever the computer sleeps or restarts I am stuck and can't boot without unplugging the DP cable again.

I read around and saw that there is notoriously an issue with bad DP cables that run power through pin 20. I checked my cable with a multimeter, and am pretty confident that pin 20 is not connected, I even covered that pin with tape before plugging into my GPU, and this didn't solve the issue.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Details:

- monitor - Samsung LC27HG70QQNXZA
- gpu - GeForce GTX 760
- OS - windows 10

Comment: We deliberately get monitors without Display Port if we can. Can you use HDMI?   That is what I would suggest.

Comment: I can, but there is a drastic change in the video quality, I bought this monitor for over $400 for good quality image, but if I need to compromise that there is no point...